# How can i add vertical line for "today" in chart.js?

Tags: charts, chart.js

How can I add a vertical dotted line to the chart indicating the current day? Later, other lines will be added as well, but the vertical line should always point to the current date. Below is a screenshot and source code.

[In the screenshot, for clarity, approximately how it should look](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h56St.png)

```
import Chart from 'chart.js/auto';
import 'chartjs-adapter-moment';

$(document).ready(function () {
    fetchChartData();
});

function fetchChartData() {
    $.ajax({
        method: 'POST',
        dataType: 'json',
        url: window.location.href + '/chart',
        data: {fetchChartData: 'fetchChartData'},
        success: function(response) {
            createChart(response.dateLabel, response.planBudget);
        },
        error: function (error) {
            console.log(error);
        }
    });
}

function createChart(labelsData, budgetData) {
    const data = {
        labels: labelsData, // ["2022-01-01 00:00:00", "2022-01-02 00:00:00", ...]
        datasets: [
            {
                label: 'remaining_budget_plan',
                backgroundColor: 'rgb(255, 99, 132)',
                borderColor: 'rgb(255, 99, 132)',
                borderWidth: 2,
                data: budgetData, // [678.77, 674.98, ...]
            },
            {
                label: 'remaining_budget',
                backgroundColor: 'rgb(0, 191, 196)',
                borderColor: 'rgb(0, 191, 196)',
                borderWidth: 2,
                data: '',
            }
        ]
    };

    const config = {
        type: 'line',
        data: data,
        options: {
            elements: {
                point:{
                    radius: 0
                }
            },
            scales: {
                x: {
                    type: 'time',
                    time: {
                        unit: 'month'
                    },
                    ticks: {
                        source: 'data'
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    };

    const myChart = new Chart(
        document.getElementById('campaignChart'),
        config
    );
}
```

Comment: You can use the annotation plugin for this: https://www.chartjs.org/chartjs-plugin-annotation/latest/

Comment: Thanks for the help. This is my first time working with this library. I installed the plugin, but I still don't quite understand how to customize it to my needs. How can I change the code from the vertical line example? I probably need to replace x with y, but what should I substitute as value? plugins: {
    autocolors: false,
    annotation: {
      annotations: {
        line1: {
          type: 'line',
          yMin: 60,
          yMax: 60,
          borderColor: 'rgb(255, 99, 132)',
          borderWidth: 2,
        }
      }
    }
  }